# RequiredFieldValidator retricting postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, requiredfieldvalidator

I have three panels which are switched by user once at a time. In one of the panel I have some validator controls. Now, whey they try submit form data with something missing it pops up. Okay. But on the other panel I also have some buttons. When those buttons are pressed, there's no postback as required field pops up on the other panel saying those fields are missing. (But the user is not actually using those textboxes.

Here's my code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/Masters/LeftBar.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Request.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_Contents_Request" EnableViewState="true"  %>

<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftBarHeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <link href="../StyleSheets/Content_Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../StyleSheets/Request_Content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Contents_Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="TopBoxContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopBoxContentHolder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="RequestScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="ItemHeaderSpace">
        <div class="TitleWrapper">
            <div class="ItemHeader">
                    <div class="ItemTitle">
                        Submit your request
                    </div>
                    <div class="ItemInfo">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="SocialButtonsHolder" class="SocialButtons" runat="server">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="ItemProfileNav">
            <li id="SubmitTab" class="Script_Tab ItemProfileNavInactive" runat="server">Sumbit request</li>
            <li id ="CheckTab" class="Script_Tab ItemProfileNavInactive" runat="server">Check request status</li>
            <li id="ViewTab" class="Script_Tab ItemProfileNavInactive" runat="server">View all request</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ItemSpace">
        <div class="ItemTabContent">
            <div id="SubmitTabContent" class="Script_TabContent" runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SubmitRequestUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="MessegeBox" class="ErrorBox" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" runat="server">
                    <p>Please try to find your content on our <a href="Index.aspx" target="_blank">index page</a>. Go to that content (<a href="Index.aspx?type=psvita" target="_blank">Games</a>, <a href="Index.aspx?type=movie>" target="_blank">Movies</a>) and request from there.
                        Creating a custom request will take more time for processing.
                    </p>
                </div>
                    <table id="SubmitRequestForm" runat="server" class="DownloadInfoTable" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Content Name: </td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="ContentTitleTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Content Type: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ContentTypeDropDown" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="PS Vita Game" Value="psvita"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="PSP ISO" Value="psp"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Movie" Value="movie"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="TV Show Episode" Value="episode"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="TV Show" Value="tvshow"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="TypeHiddenFiled" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="InfoField">Your Name*: </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" MaxLength="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameValidator" CssClass="ErrorBox" ControlToValidate="NameTextBox" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="InfoField">Your date of birth*: </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="YearDropdown" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Year" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="MonthDropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Month" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DateDropdown" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Day" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="YearValidator" CssClass="ErrorBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="YearDropdown" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="MonthValidator" CssClass="ErrorBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MonthDropdown" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="DayValidator" CssClass="ErrorBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateDropdown" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">You are a: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderDropdown" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Boy" Value="male"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Girl" Value="female"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Don't want to specify" Value="unspecified"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="InfoField">Your E-mail*: </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequitedValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="ErrorBox"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="InfoField">Your Profile Link (Optional): </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ProfileLink" runat="server" MaxLength="500"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="InfoField"></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ID="EmailValidator" CssClass="ErrorBox" ControlToValidate="EmailTextBox" runat="server" ErrorMessage="That's not a valid Email address."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="ErrorBox">All * marked fields are mandatory.</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="InfoField"></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="SubmitRequestButton" runat="server" Text="Submit your Request" CssClass="MetroButtonText SubmitButton" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="Clearfix">

                </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div id="CheckTabContent" class="Script_TabContent" runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CheckRequestPanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                <table class="DownloadInfoTable" style="width: 520px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Your Request ID: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="RequestIdTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="CheckStatusButton" runat="server" Text="Check status" CssClass="MetroButtonText" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField"></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="ForgotIDButton" CssClass="MetroButtonText" runat="server" Text="Forgot ID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div id="RequestCheckMessegeBox" class="ErrorBox" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" visible="false" runat="server">
                    <p>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <table id="RequestDetailsTable" class="DownloadInfoTable PopUpForm" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Hi, <asp:Label ID="RequestUserName" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Your Request ID: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="RequestIdLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Request submission date: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="RequestDateLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Status: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="TimeRemainingRow" runat="server" visible="false">
                        <td class="InfoField">Time remaining: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TimeRemainingLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Resolving date: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ResolvingDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Requested Content: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Hyperlink ID="RequestContentLink" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Hyperlink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Requested Content Type: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Hyperlink ID="RequestedContentTypeLink" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Hyperlink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="ForgotIDForm" class="DownloadInfoTable PopUpForm" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Your Name*: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ForgotIDNameTextBox" runat="server" Enabled="True" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Your Date of Birth*: </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ForgotIDMonthDropdown" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Month" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ForgotIDDateDropdown" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Day" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ForgotIDYearDropdown" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Year" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="ForgotIdMonthVal" CssClass="ErrorBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ForgotIDMonthDropdown" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="ForgotIdDateVal" CssClass="ErrorBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ForgotIDDateDropdown" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="ForgotIdYearVal" CssClass="ErrorBox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ForgotIDYearDropdown" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="InfoField">Your E-mail*: </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ForgotIDEmailTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="FindIDButton" CssClass="MetroButtonText" runat="server" Text="Find my Request ID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div id="ViewTabContent" class="Script_TabContent" runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ViewRequestListUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table class="DownloadInfoTable PopUpForm">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="InfoField"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="Show only pending requests" runat="server" /></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="InfoField">Number of Requests: </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="RequestNumDropdown" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="20" Value="20"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="40" Value="40"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="All requests" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="InfoField">Sort requests by: </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="SortDropdown" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Most Recent" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Content-wise" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Text="Number of requests" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="RequestListTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="RequestIdCol">Request ID</th>
                            <th class="DateCol">Date</th>
                            <th class="ContentCol">Content</th>
                            <th class="RequestNoCol">No. of requests</th>
                            <th class="StatusCol">Status</th>
                            <th class="RequestedByCol">Request by</th>
                            <th class="ResolvingDateCol">Resoving date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RequestIdCol">DKFJD09</td>
                            <td class="DateCol">01 Jan,2012</td>
                            <td class="ContentCol">Batman Begins</td>
                            <td class="RequestNoCol">5</td>
                            <td class="StatusCol">Pending</td>
                            <td class="RequestedByCol">kaushikdb</td>
                            <td class="ResolvingDateCol">01 Jan,2012</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                        <asp:Button ID="ViewMoreButton" CssClass="MetroButtonText LeftFloatButton" runat="server" Text="View More" />
                        <div class="Clearfix"></div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    ItemTabSwitch();
                    FileScroll();
                    DownloadButton();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="CommentBox">
            <div class="DivTitle">Comments on <asp:Hyperlink ID="CommentHeader" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Hyperlink> Vitagamer</div>
            <div id="Comments" class="Comments" runat="server"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="AddHolder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="SideContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

I need to be able to restrict users from submitting form only if they are forgetting something on that panel only. I want the buttons on the other panel to be able to post back when they are pressed.

What are the work arounds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Validation Groups for each panel.  If no Validation Groups are specified ASP.NET will fire all validators on the form.

[Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<div id="panel1">
    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
      controltovalidate="NameTextBox"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      errormessage="Enter your name."
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

    <asp:button id="Button1" 
      text="Validate" 
      causesvalidation="true"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      runat="Server" />
</div>
<div id="panel2">
    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
      controltovalidate="NameTextBox2"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup2"
      errormessage="Enter your name."
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

    <asp:button id="Button2" 
      text="Validate" 
      causesvalidation="true"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup2"
      runat="Server" />
</div>
```